# Highmaps Kentucky isn't highlighted when printing using US-All map

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I have a chart very similar to this demo:

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges

If you do a print preview/print in Chrome (Latest Version 46.0.2490.80 m) you will see that Kentucky is white instead of red.

I've tested it in IE and Edge (latest versions) and Kentucky is colored red like it's supposed to be.

Here is my chart with the same issue as Highmaps demo:

http://run.plnkr.co/aVxwOTRBvzU8F28j/

Has anyone else encountered this or have a solution? Is this an issue with Chrome or Highmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for feeback, looks like a bug. I reported that in our bugtracker here:
- https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4715